# How do I compare the results of two async JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have two async functions. Each function make one call to two different DBs. So function1 calls to PostGres. Function2 calls to Athena. They both return an array of integers. I need to then compare both arrays for equivalence. What's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: The title asks for how to compare two functions (which isn't clear what that even means), the question itself asks for how to compare arrays? Which one is it now? To compare arrays you iterate over them and compare each element. How to compare the elements really depends on their data types.

Comment: I updated the title to be a little more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call both functions, await the results and compare them:

```
const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([function1(), function2()]);
compare(result1, result2);
```

Comment: You need `Promise.all`. `await [...]` won't work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Promise.all` and then compare values.
Here is an Example from MDN:

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```